# How to convert position of UITextview to SKScene position?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uitextview

I need to have more than one line of text so I cannot use SKLabelNode. I want the UITextView to be positioned in a central position of the screen no matter what device is used. Problem is the coordinate system seems to be different than the GameScene and am unsure how to convert it properly. Anyone have an idea?